# Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script) - Permissions Error for Advanced Segments

Tags: google-analytics

I recently watched a video by Nicholas Blexrud on how to integrate Google Google Spreadsheet with Analytics.

The tools works great accept when adding an advanced segment.  See error below.

Error executing query1: User does not have sufficient permissions for this advanced segment.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Nicholas Blexrud... super nice guy... :)

Sounds like you weren't the one who originally created the segment, could that be the case? You should be able to recreate the segment using the same login you are using for the api. That's funny though, I've never run across the error.